# bundle gem: rspec says 'No examples found'

Tags: ruby, rspec, bundler

I am in the middle of porting part of a ruby on rails project into a gem. I have used `bundle gem` to create the new gem directory. For the `lib` and `spec` directories, the gem's project layout looks like this:

```
|- lib
|  |- mylib
|  |  |- MYCLASS.rb
|  |  |- version.rb
|  |
|  |- mylib.rb
|
|- spec
   |- spec_helper.rb
   |- mylib
      |- test_MYCLASS.rb
```

The contents of `spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
require "mylib"

RSpec.configure do |config|
end
```

The relevant parts of `mylib.gemspec`, as generated by the `bundle gem` command:

```
spec.files         = `git ls-files`.split($/)
spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
spec.test_files    = spec.files.grep(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
spec.require_paths = ["lib"]
```

When I run `bundle exec rspec spec`, I get

```
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00004 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures
```

Two questions.

1. Is my directory layout for this gem "correct"? (Assuming there is an official layout)
2. Why are my tests not running? When I do `bundle exec rspec spec/mylib/*`, the tests in `spec/mylib/test_MYCLASS.rb` run, whereas if I do `bundle exec rspec spec/mylib/`, it says no examples found.

I've looked at similar questions and googled around, but none of them solves my problem.

Comment: It seems that git did't count spec folder. please specify us with output of `git show HEAD:spec` command.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Solved it with help from my colleague. Turns out that the spec files have to be named with a `_spec` suffix, and `bundle exec rspec spec` works. I name the spec file with a `test_` prefix previously. Was using bundler 1.3.5 and rspec 2.14.1

Comment: damn, thanks. I put `_specs.rb` and that's what was causing me issues.

Comment: as well -- my spec directory was specs

Comment: Mine are properly named with the `_spec.rb` suffix, but I still have this problem.

Comment: My file was just completely empty and I had been coding in the wrong file

Answer (score 0):

Another possible issue is forgetting to `require 'rails_helper'` which is usually where you require most of your test supporting libraries, including `require 'rspec/rails'`.

Answer (score 0):

spec files not only need to be named with `_spec.rb` suffix, they also need to be in a directory called `/spec` and `rspec` need to be called from the root.